# How to sort array by months/weeks from given dataset in PHP

Tags: php, database, multidimensional-array

Given a dataset from a database I want to get new arrays in a custom order.

The dataset would look like this:

```
 $dataset = [
'val1' => ['202201' => '1', '202202' => '2', '202203' => '3', '202206' => '5', '202207' => '4'], 
'val2' => ['202201' => '54', '202202' => '43', '202203' => '12']
]
```

As you can see val1, val2, etc. are ordered by year and weeknumber which are technically DateTime objects. I am able to output this dataset now to an array ordered by weeks.

But I want to have a second array now, which aggregates these values by month like the following:

```
$perMonth = [
'2022-01' => ['val1' => '6'], //Month 1 related week values added together
'2022-02' => ['val1' => '9'] //Month 2 related week values added together
]
```

Do you have any ideas how can I approach this problem? I can't edit the database.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will have to create actual DateTime instances then from those strings, so that you can determine what month they actually fall into.

Comment: I just did that but what now?

Comment: Well now you are able to create the `YYYY-MM` key for your $perMonth array from that. So all you need to do now, is sum up the values in there, while you are looping over your input data.

Comment: Please explain how you got the sum 6 for 2022-01!

Comment: @jspit This is the behaviour I am aiming for. 2022-01 is an aggregation of 202201, 202202 & 202203 from the dataset because the three weeks belong to the first month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create actual DateTime instance from those strings, so that you can determine what month they actually fall into. Then you are able to create the `YYYY-MM` key for your `$perMonth` array from that.

So you loop over your input data, determine the `YYYY-MM` value for the current item - and sum the values up under that key in your result array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CBroe's answer here is a possible solution. The string '202201' is converted to '2022W01' with substr_replace, which can be interpreted directly by DateTime.

```
$dataset = [
'val1' => ['202201' => '1', '202202' => '2', '202203' => '3', '202206' => '5', '202207' => '4'], 
'val2' => ['202201' => '54', '202202' => '43', '202203' => '12']
];

$perMonth = [];
foreach($dataset as $val => $array){
  foreach($array as $yearWeek => $number){
    $keyYearMonth = date_create(substr_replace($yearWeek,'W',4,0))->format('Y-m');
    $perMonth[$keyYearMonth][$val] ??= 0;
    $perMonth[$keyYearMonth][$val] += $number;
  }
}

var_export($perMonth);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '2022-01' => 
  array (
    'val1' => 6,
    'val2' => 109,
  ),
  '2022-02' => 
  array (
    'val1' => 9,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you that's a very slim and simple solution!